# How to handle abort() while unit-testing Google Cloud Functions using Mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, http-error, werkzeug

The Cloud Function I am testing calls `abort(410)` and I want to test if the proper HTTP error code is received in my unit tests.

On simply making the request, I get the following error:

```sh
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py:707: in abort
    return _aborter(status, *args, **kwargs)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <werkzeug.exceptions.Aborter object at 0x7fd474096b00>, code = 410, args = (), kwargs = {}

    def __call__(self, code, *args, **kwargs):
        if not args and not kwargs and not isinstance(code, integer_types):
            raise HTTPException(response=code)
        if code not in self.mapping:
            raise LookupError('no exception for %r' % code)
>       raise self.mapping[code](*args, **kwargs)
E       werkzeug.exceptions.Gone: 410 Gone: The requested URL is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address. If you followed a link from a foreign page, please contact the author of this page.

/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py:687: Gone
```

Here is my code for making the Mock request:

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock
from cloud_functions import main

data = { ... }
headers = { ... }

req = Mock(get_json=Mock(return_value=data), args=data, headers=headers)
resp = main.my_function(req)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `HTTPException` module from `werkzeug.exceptions` to catch the error code works fine for me.

Changing my code to this makes it work now.

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock
from cloud_functions import main
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

data = { ... }
headers = { ... }

req = Mock(get_json=Mock(return_value=data), args=data, headers=headers)
try:
    resp = main.get_url_full(req)
    assert False
except HTTPException as e:
    assert e.code == 410
```